# help on question 1 from assignment 2 stanford

Tags: java, variables

Here is basically the link to the assignment material: http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/13-assignment-2-simple-java.pdf

I've completed the program but I have a few questions.

Firstly, I'm confused with the part where it says "The numbers in parentheses show the values for this diagram, but you must be able to change those values in your program."

Yet they're 3 constants that are declared and initialised as 'final', so I can't really create any mutator methods to change them. Am I missing something here?

```
/** Width of each brick in pixels */
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

/** Width of each brick in pixels */
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

/** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 14;
```

And my second question is: How am I suppose to know if my pyramid is centred when my applet view isn't fixed like the one that stanford uses? Mine is some applet viewer whereby the window can be expanded to fit the whole window.

Comment: You could improve this question by describing the assignment instead of just linking to it.  If the link goes bad, most of the value in the question will be lost.

Comment: I'm assuming that "you must be able to change those values in your program" just means that you know how to change the constants so that the program produces different output.

Comment: Please improve your question, especially the title. Not everyone is familiar with all courses from Stanford. Add at least the course title and more tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, I'm confused with the part where it says "The numbers in parentheses show the values for this diagram, but you must be able to change those values in your program."

The intent of that remark is that if you change one of those values and re-run the program, then the output still looks good and the change is visible.
For example, if you change `BRICK_HEIGHT` to 20, then *all* bricks become 20 pixels high.

> How am I suppose to know if my pyramid is centred when my applet view isn't fixed like the one that stanford uses? Mine is some applet viewer whereby the window can be expanded to fit the whole window.

If you are up for a challenge, you could try to react to resizes of the applet view, but otherwise it is probably fine if you center the pyramid in the original window.